# Php Sort Arrays That Are Linked

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays.
One is an array full of names.
The other is an array full of ages.
The values in both arrays match. Name at value x in names array matches the age at value x in the age array. I want to sort the arrays based on their ages. Can I some how link the arrays and then use something like asort or usort to sort the arrays? Or do I need to manually sort the arrays?

```
Names Array ('John','Eric','Dave')
Age Array ('11','4','10')

John is 11, Eric is 4, Dave is 10.
```

After sort the arrays would look like this.

```
Names Array ('Eric','Dave','John')
Age Array ('4','10','11')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$names = array('a', 'c', 'd', 'b');
$ages = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

array_multisort($names, $ages);

var_dump($names, $ages);
```

Reference: http://php.net/array_multisort

Code live: http://ideone.com/CGsR3q

Comment: What does var_dump do? Why is it needed?

Comment: @user2027231: http://php.net/var_dump How would you output the result to check it is sorted right?

Comment: The op has specified arrays that are linked.. So i'm guessing that he is referring to a multi-dimensional array

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Should have googled var_dump, sorry about asking without checking. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @Daryl Gill: you need to check the right answer (and upvote it) ;-)

Comment: @Daryl Gill: for some reason it was obvious for me that "linked arrays" is not a nested arrays, but 2 independent ones

Comment: What he is referring too in the question seems to me a "nested array" which the end result he wants to merge the contents of the name & age or even split the two arrays into their own different array; and that wasn't me that -1 you.